# Краюха и краюшка

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, морфемный-разбор, реклама

Вопрос навеян вот этой [рекламой](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zUmcYwpI9M):
*Представляю вам подлинный шедевр: **краюшки** "Кирде" — настоящий хит.*

Словечко заинтересовало. Нашла в [словаре Тихонова](http://www.slovorod.ru/der-tikhonov/tih-k.htm): ***краю́х/а*** и ***краю́ш/к/а***.
Такой разбор показался мне странным.
(Вот схожие слова: *раз/вал/ю́х/а*, *син/ю́х/а*. В них совсем другой принцип выделения корней и суффиксов.)

1. Скажите, а как бы вы разобрали эти слова?
2. Правильно ли называть эти прямоугольные хлебобулочные изделия *краюшками*? (Или все-таки необходимо другое слово? Какое?)

Answer (score 1):

Да, интересно. Краюшка - то же самое, что горбушка, но при этом горб/ушк/а, однако краюш/к/а.

Краюшка -уменьшительно-ласкательное от "краюха"(х//ш).

Краюха - это большой ломоть хлеба, отрезанный от края каравая. Просторечный суффикс существительного -ух-/-юх- с оттенком усилительного значения в данном слове не выделяется в результате переразложения основы. А почему произошло переразложение, почему слились корень и суффикс? Может, потому что краюха - не просто кусок чего-то, отрезанный от края, а именно большой кусок круглого каравая хлеба? Это новое значение. Вот горбушкой мы называем и корку прямоугольной буханки, и круглого хлеба, а краюхой только от каравая.

Я бы тоже **не разобрала как кра/юшк/а** - это же не "маленький край", для этого значения есть слово краешек. Краюшка, краюшки, краюшечка, краюшек, краюшкой, краюха - получается, что краюш/краюх и есть наименьшая неизменяемая часть слова.

Краюшки "Кирде" - бутерброды, где хлебная основа - разрезанная несладкая булка, но если мы поищем современное значение слова "краюшки" в смысле  выпечки, то увидим, что так называют и лепёшки, видимо просто похожие внешне на корочки ржаного хлеба. Может, это и не подходящее название, но сегодня многое называется неподходяще, маркетологи ищут необычное, звучное и в то же время знакомое.

Comment: В словарях краюшка представлен как просторечные вариант к краешек.

Answer (score 0):

Краюха - краю/х/а
Краюшка - краю/шк/а

Краюшка - уменьшительно-ласкательная форма слова "краюха".